# PHP-code blocks in templates loaded in DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument, libxml2

I need to parse HTML-template with DOMDocument. But HTML code may contain PHP-code blocks, for example:

`<div id="test" data="<?php echo $somevar?>"> </div>`

When I load this HTML I get error "Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values...". Parser thinks that attribute "data" has no closing quote and <php is new tag. How can I specify to ignore <php tag or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML code:

```
<div id="test" data="<?php echo $somevar?>"> </div>
```

Is not XML code. For XML it's invalid, HTML is okay. To load HTML code with DOMDocument, you can use the [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) function.

It will load your template without any error.

Example / [Demo](http://codepad.org/NKLLwjnx):

```
$html = '<div id="test" data="<?php echo $somevar?>"> </div>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

Related: [Can PHP include work for only a specified portion of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8509074/367456)

Comment: This really works! Thank you. But loadHTML won't accept custom tags like LoadXML, ex: http://codepad.org/4amU1ibI

Comment: Well you should decide what you want to have as language in your templates, XML or HTML. Probably XML is better working in the end as it's more flexible, but then you need to deal with the invalid attributes. But if you defined your own tags, you can skip using attributes and only use tags and enclose PHP as processing instructions (as outlined in the linked post), so then you won't have the problem at all (but some other way for writing your templates). Additionally there still is the PHP parser you can make use of to remove PHP from any file be it XML or HTML precisely.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to parse a document with PHP tags in it, you should remove those, or capture the output of the file first, and then parse it.

You can capture the output of the file with `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean();`.

You can remove the PHP tags with regex:

```
$cleaned = preg_replace("/<\?php.*?\?>/i","",$input);
```

Comment: Take care, this does not work for string definitions contiaining `?>`, `<?php echo "?>" ?>` for example.

Answer (score -1):

This feels hacky, but...

```
$doc->loadHtml(str_replace('<?php', '&lt;?php', file_get_contents($file)));
```

Comment: That would still leave echo $somevar. That's not great either.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
<div id="test" data="<?= htmlentities($somevar) ?>"> </div>
```

You can also try `htmlspecialchars()`, which is a "lighter" version of `htmlentities()`.

Comment: @saratis `<?=` is a normal part of the language and in 5.4.0 `short_open_tags` does not effect this, it is simply a shortcut for echoing content.  The problem with the answer is that loaded into a `DomDocument` you will get the same error as OP

Comment: @saratis, short tags aren't discouraged. In fact, <?= always works as of 5.4

Comment: @saratis: If you look past the shorthand tag, you will see my recommendation to use the `htmlentities()` function. _That_ would solve the specific problem at hand. The only issue with using the `<?=` shorthand tag is portability. Seeing as how most servers do support it, it's really not _that_ big an issue.

Comment: @AymanSafadi If you read the OP you will discover that he is not trying to output this, he is trying to load it into a `DomDocument` as HTML.  This is not a valid HTML string as the PHP inside the attribute never gets executed.  This string, as it is does absolutely nothing to answer the OP's question.