# How to use php include to access certain div of that included page

Tags: php, include

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can PHP include work for only a specified portion of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508511/can-php-include-work-for-only-a-specified-portion-of-a-file)

I have this syntax:

```
if ( $CountryCode == RS || $CountryCode == ME ) {
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ads/et300x250rsTEST.html ";  

}
```

I would like to access certain div o the above page for example

```
if ( $CountryCode == RS || $CountryCode == ME ) {
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ads/et300x250rsTEST.html#nameovDiv1";  

}
```

then

```
if ( $CountryCode == RS || $CountryCode == ME ) {
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ads/et300x250rsTEST.html#nameovDiv2";  

}


if ( $CountryCode == RS || $CountryCode == ME ) {
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ads/et300x250rsTEST.html#nameovDiv3";  

}
```

And make just that div visible... On page ads/et300x250rsTEST.html i would add all my advertisment in divs, and return right one when user from specific country visits the site.

Qusetion is - How to use php include to include just part of the page which is on mine server, so i have full control of it, i can add whatever code there too [et300x250rsTEST.html] ?

Thanks

Comment: why not put the div in question in a separate file and just include that

Comment: The `require` statement is exactly equivalent to copying and pasting the text in a file into this position of the current file. There is no such thing as a "div" here, just file names and copy/pasted text.

Answer (score 3):

This will not work.

You should instead call `file_get_contents` within your conditional statement. If you want to access a specific `div`, use [`DOMDocument`](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20domdocument&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), supplied by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't include just a section of a file.  You should either split the sections into different files, use functions to `echo` the text you want, or get the full contents of the file and only print out the section you want.